# Sort list of list Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of `(x, y)` in which `y` can only be 0 or 1 like this

**For example :**

```
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(5, 0), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(1, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(3, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1)]
[(5, 0), (4, 0), (5, 1)]
[(1, 1), (4, 0), (5, 1)]
[(3, 0), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(5, 0), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
[(1, 1), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
```

How can I sort the list so that the sublist with the most `y = 0` will be on the top?

Comment: What's the innermost datastructure? Is it a Pair<Integer,Integer>?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html) which sorts in ascending order (i.e. 0 before 1 etc.) in combination with `sumBy`, summing the values of y in the sublists:

```
list.sortedBy { it.sumBy { it.y } }
```

KDoc:

> Returns a list of all elements sorted according to natural sort order of the value returned by specified selector function.

You'll get a list, in which the sublists are ordered in ascending order regarding their number of elements with `y = 0`.

**Note** that summing up all `y` values as in `sumBy` only works since 0 and 1 are the only possible values in the given scenario.

Comment: he wants to sort a list of lists, not the contents of a single list

Comment: I want to sort list of list which element has more y = 0 will be on the top

Comment: @coinhndp okay understood, like this then

Comment: It will sum all the `y`s and not count zero-valued `y`.s

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah and it works since he specified y is only 0 or 1

Comment: Yes, missed that. Still, it's not very intuitive or general.

Answer (score 4):

Asuming coordinates representation below:

```
class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int)
```

You can simply use [sortedByDescending](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sorted-by-descending.html) on your list of lists and as a sorting condition [count](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/count.html) occurences of `y = 0` in sublists. With descending order the sublist with most `y = 0` will be the first.

```
val sorted = input.sortedByDescending { it.count { it.y == 0 } }
```